# How can I compile C/C++ with intel compilers for use on AMD Epyc 2 series processors? (In the most generic way)

Tags: c++, icc

I have a piece of software that is compiled with the intel mpiicc and mpiicpc compilers. I am running it on a cluster which has compute nodes with both Intel and AMD processors. It works fine on the intel processors but it does not run at all (hangs indefinitely with no error) on the AMD processors.

Cluster support believes it is due to intel specific flags causing issues, but I am not using very many flags in the compilation and the ones I am I don't think are the problem. (-fp-model, -fPIC, -m64)

So presumably if this is the issue, it is something happening automatically. Are there flags I could use to have it compile very generically with no processor specific optimizations?

I was attempting to use the flags recommended here: https://prace-ri.eu/wp-content/uploads/Best-Practice-Guide_AMD.pdf. The recommended ones "-march=core-avx2 -fma -ftz -fomit-frame-pointer" did not fix the issue, and trying the "-axHost" flag which is described there as making lowest common denominator code gave an error stating it was not supported.

Comment: _"In contrast to the Intel tools the GNU tools and tools from other independent vendors have full support for EPYC"_ - I would try g++ or one of the other alternatives to see if that helps.

Comment: I find myself wondering why Intel would have support for a competitor's CPUs. And if they did, could you trust Intel to do anything to make the competitor's chips look good?

Comment: I would just point out that Intel have been found to deliberately penalize the performance of generated code on non-Intel platforms.  This is legal as long as "disclosed", which Intel does via text in image on their website (e.g. https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/being-successful-with-the-intel-compilers-you-need-to-know.html)

Comment: @DavidJones hahaha this is the most funny thing, having it in a picture so that it doesn't get indexed, but still technically have it as a disclosure :)))))